# Is there a way to install iPhone App via browser?

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, safari

Is there a way to install iPhone App via a browser (in this case iOS Safari)?

Comment: http://appstorebeta.com is a good way to do this. It has its quirks, but overall I find it very useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, safari will detect the *.ipa and will try to install it, but the ipa needs to be correctly sign and only allowed devices would be able to install it.

http://www.diawi.com is a service that will help you with this process.

All of this is for Ad-hoc distribution and not for production apps.

Comment: Will this work on non-jailbroken phones?  Also, is there any security concerns with giving them your provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes, this will work and no there are no issues, We at our company use this for distributing releases to our clients, there various services like diawi, testflight.com is another example.

Comment: @Ecarrion Can you also give us the list of the websites that provide that service. For some reason, google doesn't return diawi at all.

Comment: Sorry, I've only used http://www.diawi.com and https://testflightapp.com but I know there are other options

Comment: Why not for production apps. I mean if it works with ad-hoc it should be working with distribution right?

Comment: Apparently some enterprise apps are not restricted to a specific list of devices, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11741111/195835

Answer (score 14):

You can use **AppBox**, A mac application that uses your Dropbox account to distribute you ad-hoc and enterprise apps, if you want to install form any other browser.

https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/releases

---

### 1 How to use AppBox

1. Link your Dropbox account with [AppBox](https://getappbox.com).
2. Select and upload the iOS application "OR" select project/workspace to archive and upload the iOS application.
3. Send the link to your testers, clients, friends or even use it yourself.
4. Open the link in the browser on the device and click on install.

## 2. Feature

- Uploaded App Expiration - Never expires. Until you delete from your Dropbox
- Unlimited app installations
- Auto Restart Upload After Network Change or Failure
- Keep same installation link for the same app
- Install previous version with same installation link
- Auto E-Mail App Distribution Link
- Maximum Upload Size - Equal to your Dropbox account storage
- Auto App Signing
- Auto Upload on Dropbox or AppStore after Archive
- Auto Shutdown Mac after Distribution
- Easy setup assistant to get started in a few minutes
- Slack, Microsoft Teams and Hangout Chat Webhook Integration
- Dashboard
- Fastlane support [read more](https://github.com/getappbox/fastlane-plugin-appbox)
- Jenkins Support [read more](https://docs.getappbox.com/ContinuousIntegration/usewithjenkinsandgitlab/)
- Dark Theme

---

## 3. AppBox vs Diawi

[image]

## 4. Screenshot

#### Upload IPA

[image]

#### Share URL

[image]

#### Dashboard

[image]

---

Give it a try from anyone of these link:

- https://getappbox.com/download
- https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/releases

Comment: when I open the link on the iOS device it says get AppBox and after downloading App Box nothing happens. Please suggest

Comment: Hi @AmitThakur, could you please provide more details on this. Or please create an issue here with complete details - https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/issues

Comment: Thanks for your response, At my end the link is https://tiny.app.link/ and when I open this link on the device it redirects me to https://getappbox.com and here it says download AppBox, and when I click on the download AppBox nothing happens.

Comment: app icon grayed out after installing from Appbox. any suggestion ?

Comment: @Ahsan, please make sure you have set application icon correctly in your project. Because AppBox doesn't modify the any content of an application.

Comment: @AmitThakur That information isn't sufficient can you provide me the complete link via email at - vineetchoudhary[at]live.in

Comment: @AmitThakur Application is installed succesfully. but the icon is grayed out and the app is not opening.

Comment: @Ahsan I think this the problem with your code. Because AppBox doesn't modify any content of your application. Please check the same IPA with another service and let me know the result. Or send me the installation link via email - vineetchoudhary[at]live.in

Comment: @VineetChoudhary I have send you a link.

Comment: @Ahsan replied via mail. P.S. - That was an app signing issue.

Comment: @VineetChoudhary do we need to add UUID's of users? or any one can directly install with link?

Comment: Hi @channu, AppBox is just OTA service. You've to sign your build with a valid provisioning profile in order to install the application. For development and ad-hoc build, you've to add device UUIDs. If you want anyone to install directly with link then you need to enrol in Apple Enterprise Program.

Comment: is it still work in 2021 ?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes. It is working.

Answer (score 4):

https://testflightapp.com/ is a good way to do this.  It has its quirks, but overall I find it very useful.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty straight forward to publish ad hoc builds on your own website. I used this tutorial to get started.
http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

Answer (score 3):

A new website BetaFamily has launched that allows you to generate installer link like diawi. You can also invite users and they will receive the installer link directly in their inbox. Below is the website link:

https://betafamily.com/supersend

Comment: It gets stuck at uploading... Then  if you try to send it, it will say "You need to upload a file". Crap in my opinion

Comment: Have you tried that again. I thing that time there may be some issue with their server. Diawi also gets the problem when there is heavy load on the server.