# make an app to install on iPhone without jailbreak and appstore

Tags: xcode, installation, jailbreak, codesign

I need to install my own app on other iPhones but without jailbreak and without the App Store!

Something like: ~~> [tui.tongbu.com](http://tui.tongbu.com)

It installs without App Store and jailbreak

Another example ~~> [sibche.ir](http://sibche.ir) ;)

I mean how they crack their apps so that it will install on non-jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741111/install-ios-app-directly-from-website-no-password-no-itunes-no-udid

Answer (score 3):

It's called wireless distribution of iOS apps. You will need to create enterprise manifest file, which is plist containing HTTP link to your ipa file.

You will need to host it somewhere and you will need to open this link in Safari or pass it to the device through MDM (Mobile Device Management), if this device is enrolled in MDM.

[Take a look at this link](http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/10/29/wireless-distribution-of-enterprise-ios-apps/)

It explains how to do enterprise manifest and distribute apps over the air.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [tool](http://macbuildserver.com/)

It lets you turn your app (in the form of a github repo) into an app that you can install straight from Safari.

A good example of this is [GBA4IOS](http://gba4iosapp.com/)

Answer (score -1):

If you add the other iPhones' UDIDs to your [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action) and create an Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile containing them, you can distribute Ad Hoc builds to these iPhones.

You can distribute over the air (aka downloading an IPA from a webpage) using exactly the same mechanism mentioned by [Victor.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422080/victor-ronin)

I've written a [script](https://github.com/rfistman/OTA/blob/master/bin/mk_ota) that takes a .ipa file, creates the various html & "manifest" file and uploads it to your web host (web host not included).