# some app that can be installed without going through the app store and without a jailbreak?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, apple-id

some app that can be installed without going through the app store and without a jailbreak? They use a mechanism of sharing of appleID，but i can't know how to use it

Comment: Read [apple's documentation on beta testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).. and please delete your question as it is too broad.... do some homework and then when you have specific doubts, ask relevant questions..

Comment: Enterprise provisioning profiles.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11741111/195835

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install iOS app without going through the AppStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381472/install-ios-app-without-going-through-the-appstore)

Answer (score 0):

You can install applications onto an iOS device using the program Xcode: 
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/