# Install iOS app without going through the AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I developed an app for iPhone.

I want to let my users install my app directly from my site not from app store for non jailbreak devices.

http://sibche.ir do that for their app. (If you open sibche.ir from iPhone you can download/install its app from site directly without appstore with download progress in menu! in non jailbreak devices.)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: may be they are using enterprise account, check out more about it here,
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Answer (score 1):

Here are few steps to follow:

1. open your browser and go to http://www.diawi.com/
2. Drop your .ipa file.
3. generate link after uploading 100%.
4. open link in your device browser and install app.

Using this you can install app in your Apple device without app store.

Comment: thanks. that's what I want. but how can I provide this for my site without any thirdparty solution

Comment: Do u mean to say u want such functionality for your website?

Comment: yes. I want to any activity controlled from my site. I see https://github.com/gknops/adHocGenerate. I this useful or related?

Answer (score 1):

please check the answer on this thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749757/4030948

In Enterprise account we can do like this.