# Automatically update iOS binary (IPA) from the app with objective-c codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa

I am creating a free iOS applications. I want to make clients to be able to download new version of my application from setting page of my app by pressing a button named download new version.

I had see this accepted answer that looks good for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23561783/1939409

Actually I am wondering whether this solution only works for ad-hoc apps or I can use `BetaBuilder` to create a IPA for my final apps that should install on non jailbreak devices too?

Also is there a way that I call this URL from my app with objective-c codes so that app itself download the IPA file and install it on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update app by providing link of app's new version only if you have generated ad-hoc or enterprise distribution build. Also your app can not download the new version on its own. You need to open browser with new version link and rest of the process will be handled by iOS.

Comment: but in the link I sent do not talk any thing about only ad-hoc. If I create and archive from my app for app-store and go through that steps it will now work for me?

Comment: I read link you provided and it talks about ad-hoc or enterprise build only.