# Is there any open source tool for distributing .ipa or apk file (enterprise .ipa file) without pushing on Appstore or play store

Tags: ios, iphone, hybrid-mobile-app

I just would like to know, is there any possible ways for sending enterprise .ipa (Not developer or ad-hoc or app-store) through any open source tool. If yes please suggest me that tool or software.

Actually flow is like we will send the .ipa file to the users by email or sms and users will get mail or sms with url (link) of that app and if tap on link then will be able to install that app.

There is Test flight and Diawi open source tool but problem is that we can’t submit enterprise .ipa through this tool.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & regards

Comment: Try this link:

--- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know HockeyApp support enterprise distribution (http://hockeyapp.net/features/), however it's not free.

Beta by Crashlytics say they support this too (http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/), but I haven't had any experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) to distribute your ipa file for testing. You can also use your own server using OTA method.

Comment: No need to send profile. Only upload ipa file and send link to tester.