# Install IPA file from server and install programmatically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to download ipa file from server and install programmatically. I want to do same kind of thing in android as well and i have found a way.

Android:
http://bpsinghrajput.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-download-and-install-apk-from.html

IOS: ?

Could you please help me.

Regards,

Sneh

Answer (score 0):

You can't install IPA's programatically from within iOS (on a non-jailbroken device).

Some other options are:

- If you are only testing then : Upload the Application to Apple's TestFlight and invite testers.
- If you are only testing then you can use a web adhoc-install.  This requires that the device that is going have the application installed is already registered in the provisioning profile.  See: http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html
- Open a direct link to the AppStore for the application you want to install from within another app.  See: [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502651/install-a-programmatically-downloaded-ipa-on-an-ios-device

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller) for that. This github gist has a few examples

https://gist.github.com/githubutilities/91ba27c2f5a135dce1a2#file-ios-hacks-md

```
# list installed app on the connected device
# it also lists the identifier of the installed packages
ideviceinstaller -l

# install ipa
ideviceinstaller -i <your-package.ipa>

# uninstall app
ideviceinstaller -U <your-app-id>
```