# Ios upload and download .app file via browser or some other app with url

Tags: ios, xcode, url, download, .app

### Using Xcode 7 to build and generate NamApp.app file

> - If i plugin USB and copy this app file to the mobile->Applications, It works fine
> - I have uploaded the same NamApp.app file on the server say https://namwebsite/path/folder/NamApp.app
> - I want to allow all my team members and managers to download and test, explore the app. But when i click on the NamApp.app, broswer opens it as directory instead of asking for download.

### Now the question is

> - Can i force browser to download NamApp.app to there Applications directly
> - If browser can not do this, is there any other app which can do this for me

### I tried

Download and install an ipa from url on iOS : **[Download and install an ipa from url on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios)**

Upload to **http://www.diawi.com** and provide the ipa file

> - I dont want do these ways
> - Simply upload and allows all to download NamApp.app via browser or some other app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We user BetaBuilder to upload iOS App to FTP server. You have to specify App link and URL on server and BetaBuilder will generate files which you need to upload to the specified URL.

This URL once hit via the browser of an iOS device will download the App.

https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder

Comment: I tried BetaBuilder also, Its not free, For me Generate button is disabled. Feel it works only if we pay.
Any other free solution

Comment: https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder   Build Project from this link. After build you will be able to find a .app file in XCode. Use that

Comment: @SujayUN https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder   Build Project from this link. After build you will be able to find a .app file in XCode. Use that

Comment: @Vikram I am new to Ios, I am not able to build the release version and find the app file of Beta Builder. Can u explain me in deatil

Comment: @SujayUN You can find it under project navigator under the Products folder.