# installation of ios app ipa file created through apple enterprise development program

Tags: ios

Is there any better way which helps to install the app directly from IPAD itself instead of using third party websites,apps like iTunes,index.html file etc.

Comment: use [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)

Comment: Upload your ipa on diawi.com it will generate a url that url you need to run in your iPhone safari then click install.

Comment: i also read abt it...is there any other methods...?

Comment: Thank u so much for ur answer...I thought there may be some other methods....

Comment: @Ramya other then see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios

Comment: I visited the link. I have created and uploaded index.html and manifest.plist file to the server as mentioned there. I get "can't connect to server" error

Comment: Is there anybody to help me....pls....