# Google Analytics for iOS App shows sessions from android device

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have distributed an app outside the apple app store.
To distribute the app, i have taken help from the following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23561783/4549304

I have also integrated **Google analytics** into my app which shows 1 session started on an android device.

[image: Google Analytics showing samsung session]
**I have following questions**

1. How is this possible, Is this google analytics bug, or something else?
2. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Assuming your app hasn't been released at all on android Its probably spam data.   Filter  your view to remove android hits.

Comment: Yes, I also feel the same, but the google analytics events are sent only when the app starts, and the 
`(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;` 
is called.
Even if it is spam, it has originated from an android device, what should i make out of that?

Comment: Google Analytics spam is sent directly to your account through the measurement protocol. There are no verification checks it's probably a script running on a server somewhere inserting what ever. So no it's not an android app doing the spamming