# OTA Installation: Install IPA on device for testing

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have generated a debug IPA using Codenameone build server, that I would like to test.

**The file is hosted online example URL below:**

https://url/directories_to_app/myapp.ipa

If I download the file above from my iOS device. I have no way of installing it (iOS only gives me options to share the IPA file). What are the additional steps that I need to do to be able to download and install the file on my iOS device?

Comment: In the build results go to the link to install on device where you will see the format of the itms link when using view source. This link leads to a plist file that you can open just save that file in your server and update the itms link to point at your local https install. It's crucial to use https since iOS 10.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to install ipa is upload ipa on below url then allowd adhoc devices can install this ipa from the url.

https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: Hi Nikunj, that's that is a viable suggestion, however we're currently automating our build process, therefore need a way of making the URL: https://url/directories_to_app/myapp.ipa to be able to install the file

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: it's my pleasure, that you got the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can drag drop ipa file in iTunes and install that on your device as well.

```
1.  Drag-and-drop IPA file into 'Apps' tab of iTunes BEFORE you connect the device.
2.  Connect your device.
3.  Select your device on iTunes.
4.  Select 'Apps' tab.
5.  Click Install button in front of app.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed something in your post, but if you are using the Codename One build servers you can install your .ipa directly from there. On your iOS device, browse to https://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html, click on the "Successful Build" message and then click on 'Install On Device".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install your app using http://installipa.com/

1. Click on the Enter App Details button
2. Upload your .IPA by clicking the cloud icon beside "IPA URL"
3. Optionally add a name, icon and your email address.
4. Press "Send Installation Link"

You will see a QR code, that you can scan using your iPhone, or click the link in your email from your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://appforshare.io with no limitations
No build expiry
No size limited
No storage limit
Complete project management
I have found this tool very useful as compare to others, all others limiting me if build size exceeds 50mb or 100mb, or link expires very soon etc.