# How to create .ipa file so the users can download and install like AppStore?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, installation, ipa

I want to create an `app-store-like` application ,I have an enterprise account and i unsigned applications with`iResign`,but when i upload the `.ipa` on server it doesn't show alert for installing and downloading the apps and doesn't start to download `ipa`.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios),they said to create `.index` and `info.plist` ,but i  don't have `.plist` of Applications ,for example instagram, facebook and etc, I don't have `bundle-identifier` or `bundle-version` for those applications.

What should i do for downloading and installing `.ipa` of applications?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple plist which you can use.

[image]

Follow the below link for more explanation [link](http://www.aymericlamboley.fr/blog/install-an-ipa-on-ios-directly-from-a-url/)

Comment: I want to create  app-store application, and i don't have bundle -identifier every  of apps, for example istagram and facebook and whatsApp and etc,  then this answer not work for me