# Direct download and install ipa on iPhone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, redirect

I already referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios)

I have a simple page where a user can download the iOS application from my server. The plist URL is

`<a charset='UTF-8' href='itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<?php echo $ios_plist_url; ?>' >IOS Application</a>`

When user clicks on above link then the safari browser prompts for app install. Which is expected behavior. But the problem is that when I try to redirect to the plist URL directly then the browser first prompts `Open this page in "App Store?"` and if user clicks `Open` then it will prompt for `"Install"`. Is there any way to bypass this app store alert?

Please suggest.

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>items</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>url to ipa</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>full-size-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <false/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>logo.png</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>display-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <false/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>logo.png</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>bundle</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>1.0.</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>subtitle</key>
            <string>XYZ</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>App Title</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>`
```

Comment: Which manifest url are you using? Can you please share it?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh edited the question.Please check.

Comment: What is the value for $ios_plist_url?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh : Its the url of the manifest plist file.

Comment: So you have uploaded manifest and ipa into your server, correct?

Comment: @VedPandya : `when I try to redirect to the plist URL directly` what does that mean? you are clicking on the hyperlink...right? `<a charset='UTF-8' href='itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<?php echo $ios_plist_url; ?>' >IOS Application</a>`

Comment: @VedPandya if your manifest url is not correct then you are not able to download the application. So what url are you put at there, kind show it.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh : Please read the question properly. He doesn't have the problem of downloading he has a problem with the alert only.

Comment: @Poles I think alert is based on url.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh : the url is like https://myWeb.com/yourappname/manifest.plist . How can be it based on url?

Comment: @Poles when I try to redirect to the plist URL directly what does that mean? Mean I don't want to make my user click the download link. Instead I just want to make it direct download.

Comment: remove `<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">` and try once.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot bypass the dialogue. This is the default behavior for install link (from app store).

For test builds (Adhoc) it directly prompts for installation.

For reference, please check [The Weather Channel](https://weather.com/apps) on your iPhone safari browser.

Comment: That is a real appstore link. But @VedPandya's link is different than app store.

Comment: If browser prompts Open this page in "App Store?" means AppStore app link is provided in plist file.

Comment: But in Ved Pandya's case the url is not a app store url.

Comment: @Poles In the plist (in question) he has placeholder <string>url to ipa</string>, so I am not sure where is the application downloaded from....but if he getting that dialogue tell that the application is referenced from AppStore and in this case you can not avoid the dialogue.