# Install ios app from url with customized pop-up

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking at this post to add downloading and installing app from url to my app: [Download and install an ipa from url on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios)

But, one problem is that the manifest.plist is uploaded to dropbox, and thus when calling "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url= " , safari shows alert:

[IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRpPr.png)

My question is how to customize the pop-up description: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install... to something else

plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>items</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>Ipa dropbox link</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.myapp</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>1.0.3</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>App name</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the plist?

Comment: Can you look at my plist added to the post!