# Install ad-hoc ipa

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Through my react-native app I am trying to make the user able to install another enterprise app. The link to the second app looks like this

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com//667/app-667.plist?token=jhsdbafkjkwdsfqkjdwkdjqs
```

I tried to open the URL using Linking

```
Linking.openURL(url)
```

and also using WebView

```
<View>
  <WebView
   source={{uri: this.state.appUrl}}
  />
```

But nothing happens. Have you an idea aboout the issue?
To use Linking shall I link RCTLinking to my project? I read something about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. In general, it doesn't matter from where you want to install the app from browser or from your app.
2. If you don't have Enterprise Developer Program, it is not possible.
3. The app should be upload to a server with the supported files for it. Files should be configured for thees build.

Detail explanation you can find here: [Download and install an ipa from url on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios)