# How to install .ipa file by using private URL in iPhone?

Tags: ios, server, app-store, app-store-connect

I have created the private enterprise app and converted it as .ipa file. Now I have to download the .ipa file from our private browser and I have to install it in iPhone.

[I have referred this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23561783/8186918)

I have done everything what and all mentioned in that link.. While searching in safari I am getting like this...

[image]

But still i am not getting any solution. so anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: DId you use beta builder app as told in the link?

Comment: What error or message do you get? Is your web link using HTTPS?  Is your manifest file valid and pointing to the correct ipa location? Are you opening the manifest file from safari?  What link format are you using for the manifest? (You can obfuscate the server address if you want to add the details to your question)

Comment: I have edited my question.. please refer..

Comment: The install link in your html file refers to a http web site (paypre.info)- this won't work. The plist file must be served by a https url