# How to update android app automatically without user interaction in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, auto-update, auto

I am making an android app for android tv which runs the whole day. There is no man to manually update the application and play store also does not actually update the application instantly even when settings are set for auto-update.

How can I achieve this either with 3rd party application or play store or programmatically

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this library:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_autoupdate
2. https://pub.dev/packages/new_version

Also, you should check this one: [Flutter automatically update application when new version is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811133/flutter-automatically-update-application-when-new-version-is-available)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think flutter_autoupdate meets the requirement

Comment: My requirement is  there should be no user interaction for an update as there is no operator of the tv I am making the application for