# Is it possible to test an app in an iOS device without having a Mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

I believe this is a duplicate question, but examining the others I could not find my problem exactly.

I have developed a flutter app and I intend to publish it. So I rented a virtual Mac, loaded the project in XCode and tested it on a simulator. Everything worked fine.

I have an Apple Developer Account, Certificates, registered an iPhone, etc., but it seems that I have to physically connect the device to the computer to be able to run it on the iPhone. No way to do that remotely (I'm in Brazil and the virtual Machine in NY).
XCode tells me to plug in the device so it can register it (but I have registered it already in the developer's site).

I thought it would be possible to generate some kind of executable to download to my iPhone, but it appears that is note the case.

Is there any other way I can do that?

Maybe I can skip this step and try to publish the app, because it is the same project as an Android app already tested and published in Play Store.

Comment: Can you archive? If so you can export to TestFlight and so download to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the modern answer is probably TestFlight. But this has always been possible using OTA downloads. To do this, archive your app, create an OTA manifest and put this on a web server somewhere. Then you can download the app straight to your phone (assuming it's signed with the correct provisioning profile and all that).  We used to do this a lot before TestFlight came along.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-self-hosted-url-on-ios) and
this [article](https://medium.com/healthify-tech/install-ipa-over-the-air-dropbox-36857d6add37) are somewhat related to what you want to do

Comment: Yeah, TestFlight is so simple that I forgot about OTA.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble to test without an iphone what I did is register this device on my account https://messapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/udid.png and so far I could build the app for iOS.