# Downloadable app in browser for IOS

Tags: ios, css, html, browser

In in my html-file I want to create a link for IOS-Users to download the IPA-File (app) I created. But when I upload it normally it's not downloadable.

Could anyone be kind and help me please?

Or does anyone know where I could upload a 103 MB big IPA-File for others to download it? (For free? If not for free its also okay)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650364/is-there-a-way-to-install-iphone-app-via-browser

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that . 
you need to add the **udid iphone** in the certificat when you build IPA and use some programme like ([anytrans](https://www.imobie.fr/anytrans/download.htm)) to transfer the IPA to iphone .

and make sure you are export the IPA **for Testing instead Appstore with (ad-hoc)**

Comment: Thanks very much for the info! It helps a lot :)

Comment: i used Unity and xCode to produce the IPA file

Comment: if you want to installe the app in  your iphone without sending into app store you need to add the udid Iphone in your project before export the ipa in xcode for working in your iphone , or you can send your app in App store and when approved you can download the app from any mobile

Comment: I uploaded it to the Appstore already but I can't use Https in my App. which I need because of that I'm trying to upload it to a server where I can download from with https.
Apple says you have to make a documentary for it and have zertificates but I can't get them.

Answer (score 0):

To download and install an iPA-File, you must use a secure protocol such as https !
You can also use **.plist** to install the IPA file !

To install an IPA file, we need to use the following procedure on the HTML page :

```html
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.plist">DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL IPA FILE !</a>
```

You can use www.dropbox.com to upload ipa files : [This Site](https://www.dropbox.com)

[Use this method to convert indirect links to direct links from dropbox.com](https://youtu.be/4TJ4gE3UqyA)

Note : **Unfortunately, the App Store does not allow installing unknown apps !**

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted actually to upload it to the Appstore but we use in our Game Https and apple dosen't allow Https until you give a reason for it....
Also you need a extra document for explaination to use Https :/

Comment: Cant we just go to setting->general->device management->click app -> trust app 
to allow using third party app ??

Comment: @PratikKhadka please. It's apple.